# I am getting cmake error

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Straight dump of the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/helloworld_ws/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    code = generate_environment_script('/home/ubuntu/helloworld_ws/devel/env.sh')
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/environment_cache.py", line 62, in generate_environment_script
    env_after = ast.literal_eval(output.decode('utf8'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    ROS_DISTRO was set to 'Ardent' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python
  "/home/ubuntu/helloworld_ws/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:198 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/helloworld_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/helloworld_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324528/i-am-getting-cmake-error/) by [prajyot](https://answers.ros.org/users/41967/prajyot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-03**:
Are you mixing ROS 1 and ROS 2?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-06-03**:
Also do you want to tell us some more about what you're trying to do. Posting us little more than an error message isn't very helpful.

**Comment by [prajyot](https://answers.ros.org/users/41967/prajyot/) on 2019-06-04**:
yes I first installed ROS1 with kinetic distribution and then I know about ros2 which support real time interface so also  installed ROS2 with kinetic distribution. I also getting roscore problem when I run roscore command. So how do I fix it.Thanks for help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
A work-around would be to not (auto) `source` the ROS 2 Ardent `setup.bash` file.

ROS 1 `catkin` should probably be fixed to not error-out with this setup, but if you don't `source` the ROS 2 setup file it should work as normal.

Also: why did you install Ardent? That is 4 ROS 2 releases old now (and no longer supported afaik).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
So how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for help. I fixed the problem.

---

Originally posted by [prajyot](https://answers.ros.org/users/41967/prajyot/) with karma: 16 on 2019-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0